# vim-flake8 is not working

Tags: python, vim, pyflakes, flake8

I installed [vim-flake8](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8) by git cloning it on my Pathogen bundle folder as usual, but when I tried to run the plugin pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> or using `:call Flake8()` in one Python file I receive the following message:

> Error detected while processing function Flake8:
>
> line    8:
>
> File flake8 not found. Please install it first.

Anyone has some clue about what is going on ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you didn't install the program [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8). Install it.

Assuming pip is installed

```
pip install flake8
```

should work.

Comment: Hi, Can somebody explain me why this solution doesn't work for me but installing flake from the apt repository it works?

Comment: @AbyW Maybe python 3 vs python 2 issue?

Comment: Actually you code worked and installed flake8.
But When I tried to use Vim with vim-flake8 plug didn't work.

Answer (score 7):

If installing flake8 via pip is not working try this:

```
apt-get install flake8
```

Worked for me.

Comment: hmm. I previously installed just `python-flake8`, and that didn't work by itself, but its a dependency for flake8 (according to `apt-cache show flake8`). Now its working (WSL, Debian, vim)

Answer (score 4):

If you installed flake8 already and that error occurred still, then call flake8 using absolute path.

To do this, edit line 73 of `~/.vim/autoload/flake8.vim` as following:

`call s:DeclareOption('flake8_cmd', '', '"/absolute/path/to/flake8"')`

Answer (score 4):

```
pip install flake8
```

and if you run into permission errors:

```
sudo -H pip install flake8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OSX and you're still having this problem, this solved it for me. Just run the following command in your terminal.

```
ln -s ~/.vim/bundle/vim-flake8/plugin ~/.vim/bundle/vim-flake8/ftplugin
```

And I haven't tried [this solution](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8/issues/13#issuecomment-161026086) yet, but apparently you can just add `filetype plugin on` to your `.vimrc` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `.vimrc`

```
let g:flake8_cmd = '/path/to/flake8'
```

That implies, of course, you have installed `flake8` on your computer. I have installed it using pip3 on Mac OS X, it wasn't in the path, the plugin threw an exception, and Google brought me here. 
[The variable was added back in 2012 already](https://github.com/nvie/vim-flake8/pull/9/commits/2fee056f1d3ba41d9cfc090084819c4a6b5e16ca)